# Reset password is missing on my free sandbox instance

Tags: customer-portal, user

My reset button for users is missing on my dev instance does anyone know how to enable it ? 
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to have the "Reset User Passwords and Unlock Users" permission enabled on your profile.

> **Reset User Passwords and Unlock Users** - Unlock users whose accounts
>   are locked, and reset user passwords.

Please verify whether your profile has this permission.

[image]

Comment: can't seem to find those permissions do you know where they are ?

Comment: Setup -> Administration Setup --> Manage Users --> Profiles --> Your Profile --> System Permissions

Comment: It seems like there is no such thing as system permissions. Only: Console Settings,  Page Layouts, Field-Level Security, Connected App Access, Tab Settings, Record Type Settings, Administrative Permissions, General User Permissions, Standard Object Permissions, Custom Object Permissions, Session Settings

Comment: Looks like you are using old profile layout. Please navigate as below: Setup -> Administration Setup --> Manage Users --> Profiles --> Your Profile --> Administrative Permissions.

Comment: API Enabled Not Checked Password Never Expires Not Checked
Create and Own New Chatter Groups Checked Select Files from Salesforce Checked
IP Restrict Requests Not Checked Send Outbound Messages Checked
Manage Unlisted Groups Not Checked Share internal Knowledge articles externally Not Checked
Moderate Communities Feeds Not Checked Use Identity Features Not Checked
Moderate Communities Files Not Checked View Global Header Not Checked       . Those are the only checked and unchecked fields available

Comment: Updated the answer.